# How to sum digits of an integer in java?

Tags: java

I am having a hard time figuring out the solution to this problem. I am trying to develop a program in Java that takes a number, such as 321, and finds the sum of digits, in this case 3 + 2 + 1 = 6. I need all the digits of any three digit number to add them together, and store that value using the % remainder symbol. This has been confusing me and I would appreciate anyones ideas.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the digital root of any three digit number? If so, which part is causing you trouble?

Comment: Well im just trying to take any number such as 480 and have it equal all of its digits (4, 8, 1) to add together using the % symbol. I need to create a loop in Java that can do this.

Comment: need to finish this code: Public static void main(String[] args) { int digits = 321; int sum.....   System.out.printIn(sum);   }

Comment: @ShaneLarsen have a look at the answer

Comment: It seems like you already have the number as an int - I had assumed your input was a string - (otherwise I don't really understand which part of this essentially mathematical problem is causing you trouble)

Comment: No [tag:parsing] required here, just arithmetic.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 321;
        int sum = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            sum = sum + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        System.out.println(sum); 
}
```

**Output**

```
6
```

Comment: its not running in my compiler the way it is.

Comment: This works.  @ShaneLarsen class, interface or enum expected usually means your missing a curly bracket.

Comment: It's obiouds OP is asking to do his homework, and hasn't even put the main function into a class.

Comment: actually i did input it into a class.

Answer (score 26):

A simple solution using streams:

```
int n = 321;
int sum = String.valueOf(n)
    .chars()
    .map(Character::getNumericValue)
    .sum();
```

Answer (score 5):

Recursions are always faster than loops!

Shortest and best:

```
public static long sumDigits(long i) {
    return i == 0 ? 0 : i % 10 + sumDigits(i / 10);
}
```

Comment: Are you _really_ sure they are always faster? Or just shorter?

Comment: if you need **constant time** solution check my answer.

Comment: Recursions are always faster ahahahaha that was a nice joke !

Comment: Recursion is not necessarily faster. In fact, it is very expensive in terms of space complexity, so if you have a loop solution, I recommend using that over recursion.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Recursion

```
//Sum of digits till single digit is obtained
public int sumOfDigits(int num) 
        {
            int sum = 0;

            while (num > 0)
            {
                sum = sum + num % 10;
                num = num / 10;
            }

            sum = (sum <10) ? sum : sumOfDigits(sum);

            return sum;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you love constant time try this:

```
double d = 10984.491;

// converting to String because of floating point issue of precision
String s = new String(d + "").replaceAll("\\D+","");
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);      

System.out.println(i % 9 == 0 ? 9 : i % 9);
```

Logic is if you add any number by 9, resulting addition of digit will result in the same number.

> *Example*: 6 + 9 = 15 then 1 + 5 = 6 (again you got 6).

In case of decimal point, remove it and add resulting digits.

Below code does the trick:

```
i % 9 == 0 ? 9 : i % 9
```

Comment: It's not the answer to the question, cause this solution sums recursively, for ex:
`456 -> 4+5+6 = 15 -> 1+5 = 6`, indead of `456 -> 4+5+6 = 15`
But it fits my case, so +1 :)

Comment: I can't see any recursion. This solution is just wrong.

Answer (score 3):

*without mapping ➜ the quicker lambda solution*

```
Integer.toString( num ).chars().boxed().collect( Collectors.summingInt( (c) -> c - '0' ) );
```

*…or same with the slower % operator*

```
Integer.toString( num ).chars().boxed().collect( Collectors.summingInt( (c) -> c % '0' ) );
```

*…or Unicode compliant*

```
Integer.toString( num ).codePoints().boxed().collect( Collectors.summingInt( Character::getNumericValue ) );
```

Comment: Is this actually quicker? Or just the quicker version in lambda form?

Comment: Yes, I think it is always quicker. Mapping takes time and, btw, is superfluous here. Which doesn't mean there are no faster non-lambda solutions — the creation of the stream needs extra time. Nevertheless, the speed advantage for an accustomed solution in the present example should be of a more homeopathic nature.

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't you be able to do it recursively something like so? I'm kinda new to programming but I traced this out and I think it works.

```
int sum(int n){
return n%10 + sum(n/10);
}
```

Comment: I would add an if-check in there somewhere, because currently `sum` will call itself infinitely causing this site's host-error ;) (`StackOverflowError`). Something like `int sum(int n){ if(n > 9){ return n%10 + sum(n/10); } return n;}`

Answer (score 1):

[**Click here to see full program**](http://programmersinterview.blogspot.com/2015/10/java-program-for-sum-of-digits.html)

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int number = 333;
    int sum = 0;
    int num = number;
    while (num > 0) {
        int lastDigit = num % 10;
        sum += lastDigit;
        num /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of digits : "+sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be working fine for any number of digits and it will return individual digit's sum

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a string");
    String numbers = input.nextLine();  //String would be 55
    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : numbers.toCharArray()) {
        sum += c - '0';
    }
    System.out.println(sum); //the answer is 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8,

```
public int sum(int number) {
  return (number + "").chars()
                      .map(digit -> digit % 48)
                      .sum();
}
```

Converts the number to a string and then each character is mapped to it's digit value by subtracting ascii value of '0' (48) and added to the final sum.

Answer (score 1):

Sums all the digits regardless of number's size.

```
private static int sumOfAll(int num) {
    int sum = 0;

    if(num == 10) return 1;

    if(num > 10) {
        sum += num % 10;
        while((num = num / 10) >= 1) {
            sum += (num > 10) ? num%10 : num;
        }
    } else {
        sum += num;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @Kaplan True. Thanks. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

The following method will do the task:

```
public static int sumOfDigits(int n) {
    String digits = new Integer(n).toString();
    int sum = 0;
    for (char c: digits.toCharArray())
        sum += c - '0';
    return sum;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
System.out.printf("Sum of digits = %d%n", sumOfDigits(321));
```

Comment: `new Integer(n)` is wasteful. Just call `Integer.toString(n)` or `String.valueOf(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, this is possible in a single line of code as follows:

```
int sum = Pattern.compile("")
        .splitAsStream(factorialNumber.toString())
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be little late ..but here is how you can do it recursively

```
public int sumAllDigits(int number) {
    int sum = number % 10;

    if(number/10 < 10){
        return sum + number/10;
    }else{
        return sum + sumAllDigits(number/10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a one-liner I guess this is a very nice solution:

```
int sum(int n){
  return n >= 10 ? n % 10 + sum(n / 10) : n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 Recursive Solution, If you dont want to use any streams.

```
UnaryOperator<Long> sumDigit = num -> num <= 0 ? 0 : num % 10 + this.sumDigit.apply(num/10);
```

How to use

```
Long sum = sumDigit.apply(123L);
```

Above solution will work for all positive number. If you want the sum of digits irrespective of positive or negative also then use the below solution.

```
UnaryOperator<Long> sumDigit = num -> num <= 0 ? 
         (num == 0 ? 0 : this.sumDigit.apply(-1 * num)) 
         : num % 10 + this.sumDigit.apply(num/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 Solution:

```
int n= 29;    
String.valueOf(n).chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @saurabhkumar Why do you say doesn't work..?
I added screenshots..

Comment: sorry added comment in wrong place

Comment: u can delete the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

We should not just try to solve it with recursion but also look for optimized ways of solving it. One such option is using **tail recursion**. Space complexity of recursive algorithms increases when the depth of recursion increases, which can be optimized using tail recursion

```
public class SumOfDigits {

    public int tailRecursiveSumOfDigits(int number, int accumulator)
    {

        if(number < 10)
            return accumulator + number;
        else{
            int remainder = number % 10;
            return tailRecursiveSumOfDigits(number/10, remainder + accumulator);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SumOfDigits sod = new SumOfDigits();
        System.out.println(sod.tailRecursiveSumOfDigits(1234,0));

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be too late, but I see that many solutions posted here use O(n^2) time complexity, this is okay for small inputs, but as you go ahead with large inputs, you might want to reduce time complexity. Here is something which I worked on to do the same in linear time complexity.

NOTE : The second solution posted by Arunkumar is constant time complexity.

```
    private int getDigits(int num) {
    int sum =0;
    while(num > 0) { //num consists of 2 digits max, hence O(1) operation
        sum = sum + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }   
    return sum;
}
public int addDigits(int N) {
    int temp1=0, temp2= 0;
    while(N > 0) {
        temp1= N % 10;
        temp2= temp1 + temp2;
        temp2= getDigits(temp2); // this is O(1) operation
        N = N/ 10;
    }
    return temp2;
}
```

Please ignore my variable naming convention, I know it is not ideal. Let me explain the code with sample input , e.g. "12345". Output must be 6, in a single traversal.

Basically what I am doing is that I go from LSB to MSB , and add digits of the sum found, in every iteration.

The values look like this

Initially temp1 = temp2 = 0

```
N     | temp1 ( N % 10)  | temp2 ( temp1 + temp2 )
12345 | 5                | 5   
1234  | 4                | 5 + 4 = 9 ( getDigits(9) = 9)
123   | 3                | 9 + 3 = 12 = 3 (getDigits(12) =3 )
12    | 2                | 3 + 2 = 5 (getDigits(5) = 5)
1     | 1                | 5 + 1 = 6 (getDigits(6) = 6 )
```

Answer is 6, and we avoided one extra loop.
I hope it helps.

Comment: "This is O(1) operation": no it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

Mine is more simple than the others hopefully you can understand this if you are a some what new programmer like myself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class DigitsSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int digit = 0;
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        digit = in.nextInt();
        int D1 = 0;
        int D2 = 0;
        int D3 = 0;
        int G2 = 0;
        D1 = digit / 100;
        D2 = digit % 100;
        G2 = D2 / 10;
        D3 = digit % 10;


        System.out.println(D3 + G2 + D1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answers here, I can explain a little bit. It is actually a mathematical problem.

321 is the total of 300 + 20 + 1.

If you divide 300 by 100, you get 3.

If you divide 20 by 10, you get 2.

If you divide 1 by 1, you get 1.

At the end of these operations, you can sum up all of them and you get 6.

```
public class SumOfDigits{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myVariable = 542;
    int checker = 1;
    int result = 0;
    int updater = 0;

    //This while finds the size of the myVariable
    while (myVariable % checker != myVariable) {
        checker = checker * 10;
    }

    //This for statement calculates, what you want.
    for (int i = checker / 10; i > 0; i = i / 10) {

        updater = myVariable / i;
        result += updater;
        myVariable = myVariable - (updater * i);
    }

    System.out.println("The result is " + result);
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple program for sum of digits of the number 321.

```
  import java.math.*;

        class SumOfDigits {
            public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                int sum = 0;
                int i = 321;
                    sum = (i % 10) + (i / 10);
                        if (sum > 9) {
                            int n = (sum % 10) + (sum / 10);
                            System.out.print("Sum of digits of " + i + " is " + n);

                        }else{
                           System.out.print("Sum of digits of " + i + " is " + sum );     

    }

                }
        }


Output:

Sum of digits of 321 is 6
```

Or simple you can use this..check below program.

```
public class SumOfDigits {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    long num = 321;

/*  int rem,sum=0;
    while(num!=0)
    {
        rem = num%10;
        sum = sum+rem;
        num=num/10;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

    */
    if(num!=0)
    {
        long sum = ((num%9==0) ? 9 : num%9);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```