# a loop that takes a 3 digit number and adds the numbers together

Tags: java

I'm trying to write as loop in java that takes a 3 digit number and adds the numbers together. For example 123 would equal 6. I know that n % 10 will get me the first digit 3 and then n/10 will get me 23 which can than then can be % 10 again to get me the second number. That doesn't work for the last number however. I can't figure out how to write the loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `%10` gets you the 10's place, `%100` gets you the 100's place, etc... see the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 321;
        int sum = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            sum = sum + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Duplicate: [How to sum digits of an integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096670/how-to-sum-digits-of-an-integer-in-java)

Comment: Don't repost answers, just flag the question as a duplicate.