# Algorithm from Cracking the Coding Interview seems to be doing something wrong

Tags: algorithm, sum

I'm a CS student and I bought Cracking the Coding Interview about a week ago. I'm just at the Big O chapter and I found an algorithm which supposedly sums the digits in a number; it looked confusing at a first glance so I ran it in Python but it did not do what it was supposed to. Have a look:

```
int sumDigits(int n) {
  int sum= 0;
  while (n > 0) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

From what I understand, this code does not actually return the sum of the digits of a given number, or does it? I really want to see how it does this but since the example I tried in Python did not work I really can't see how this works.

Comment: if you need single digit output, then `n % 9 != 0 ? n % 9 : 9` more details are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096670/how-to-sum-digits-of-an-integer-in-java/45780174#45780174

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm depends on `n /= 10` being [integer division](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html) (i.e `5/2 === 2`).  If you're using Python 3, you'll need to use `//` so it should probably look like this:

```
def sumDigits(n):
    sum = 0
    while n > 0: 
        sum += n % 10
        n //= 10  # integer division

    return sum

sumDigits(123)  # 6
```

Comment: It would be more accurate to say "if you're using Python 3", since the change to the semantics of `/` was part of Python 3 from the beginning. The truncating division operator `//` was introduced in Python 2.2, in 2001.

Comment: Thanks @rici, I wasn't sure when that change happened…

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct and would work as intended. You can dry run the code. Take for example the number 1234. 
Here is the output after each iteration of the ***while*** loop.

Sum    Number
   0         1234
   4         123
   7         12
   9         1
  10        0

It is evident that in each iteration of the while loop, the last digit given by ***n % 10*** is added to the sum. Also, the number itself is divided by 10 (***n /= 10***) in the next step so that the *2nd* last digit now becomes the last digit post division and can safely be added to the sum.

Comment: It had to do with integer division (I had to use // instead of /).