# Find Sum of digits for given number in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose

Example1: number is 37
Sum of numbers is 3+7= 10

Ex2:
Number is 1000
Sum of numbers is 1+0+0+0 = 1.

My first approach was converting number to string and then char array. With that I could use stream in which I converted chars to their int values which let me performed sum.

But is there any utility method in Stream API which could improve it?

Comment: Sorry i given in tags. Now updated qustion.

Comment: I'll guess you would have to implement an custom `Spliterator`, but this is not a beginners task. Suggest to learn `while` loops first.

Comment: Ok. I tryied to do with converting number to string then char array.. then stream. Then intValue from stream. Then performed sum. Is there any utility method i am asking? Or simple way

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35072547/14159142

Comment: @Gyro.. i used while loop with reminder concept. But  It is taking more than 5sec. There is time limit for that.

Comment: Yes. It is helping me. Thankyou @I4zs

Answer (score 4):

```
    public long getSumOfDigits(int number)
    {
        return Stream.of(String.valueOf(number).split(""))
                .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::parseInt))
                .getSum();
    }
```