# Read index and strings from text file Java

Tags: java

Suppose i have a text file that has a number code and a string label on each line:

```
0102 Apple Banana Code
0203 Pear Watch Time
0405 Java Computer Pen
0607 Car Bike Drive
```

How could i print the sum of the non zero numbers in the front and the first two words of each line? Assuming that the numbers are always 4 digits and words are separated by a single space from the number and in between the words.
For example I would get:

```
3 Apple Banana 
5 Pear Watch 
9 Java Computer 
13 Car Bike
```

I have tried to initialize this but i have no idea where to go from here

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fr);
String[][] words = new String[100][];
String line;
int size = 0;
while((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
    words[size++] = line.split(" ");
}
inFile.close();
```

Comment: You can use `Intstream`. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67609220/4347350

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Refer to below code. Explanations appear after the code.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Tester {
    private static void handleLine(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int num = handleNumber(parts[0]);
        System.out.printf("%d %s %s%n", num, parts[1], parts[2]);
    }

    private static int handleNumber(String number) {
        char[] digits = number.toCharArray();
        int total = 0;
        for (char digit : digits) {
            total += digit - '0';
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Path.of("tragedy.txt");
        try (BufferedReader inFile = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            String line = inFile.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                handleLine(line);
                line = inFile.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- I use class [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) to create a `BufferedReader` but it is not required. Your code for obtaining a `BufferedReader` is correct.
- I also use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that the file is closed.
- You asked how to print the file lines after manipulating them slightly so that is what the above code does.
- `char` is actually a number so to get the actual number value from the `char`, I subtract the value of the `0` character.