# In this Java's char array code - what is the purpose of sum += c - '0' line?

Tags: java

I am new to Java Programming and I stumbled upon below copy pasted code ( which I found from: [How to sum digits of an integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096670/how-to-sum-digits-of-an-integer-in-java))

I am struggling to understand this code and basically would like an explanation on the following line:
sum += c -'0';
What does this line evaluate to? and what is the purpose of -'0' ?

thanks all in advance.

> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> ```
> public class RandomPractice1 {
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
>             System.out.println("enter some digits: ");
>          String digits = input.nextLine();  //try digits 55
>         int sum = 0;
>         for (char c : digits.toCharArray()) {
>             sum += c -'0';
>             
>     }
>         
>         System.out.printf("sum of numbers %s is %d\n", digits, sum); //the answer is 10
> }  }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`char` values in Java have an integer representation, but it doesn't correspond to their integer value. `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is 49, and so on.

Assuming you only enter decimal digits, then subtracting `'0'` from each `char` is one way to get their apparent integer values, so that when you sum them you get the expected total.

Comment: thank you! does this mean that sum += c -'0'; is equivalent to sum = sum + c - '0'. For example: if input is 55, then would it be read as: sum = 0 + 53 - 48 = 5?

Comment: @12InchesUnBuffed Yes, exactly right for the first time through the loop. (In the second, the old sum of 0 would be replaced with 5.)

Comment: oh okay i see so basically it is necessary for the loop to move to the next position? otherwise, without the +=, the code will not execute through the loop? I tried to remove the += and replaced with only = 
and my output shows as 5. It seems that the code ignores the first char '5' and only executes the last char '5' minus char '0'. Am I understanding the mechanics correctly? or am I misunderstanding? thank you a lot for your time and help!

Comment: @12InchesUnBuffed Yes `sum += c -'0'` is adding a value to sum and overwriting the old sum. `sum = c -'0'` is just assigning a new value to sum without adding, so you'd end up with *only* the last value in the loop.